ffmpeg combine filters for audio and video
I am trying to use hue=s=0 alongside replacing audio using ffmpeg.  I have this originally:
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i 'source.mp4' -filter_complex "amovie='audio.mp3':loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[aud]" -map 0:v -map '[aud]' -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k -shortest 'out.mp4' 
This works great.  Audio is replaced.  Now I want to turn it black and white so I try to add hue=s=0:
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i 'source.mp4' -filter_complex "hue=s=0,amovie='audio.mp3':loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[aud]" -map 0:v -map '[aud]' -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k -shortest 'out.mp4' 
This fails.
I tried:
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i 'source.mp4' -filter_complex "[0:v]hue=s=0;amovie='audio.mp3':loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[aud]" -map 0:v -map '[aud]' -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k -shortest 'out.mp4' 
This fails as well.
How can I combine these two filters?
Thank you!

The error I got from your command is following:

Streamcopy requested for output stream fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.

You're telling ffmpeg to copy the video stream. However to apply a video filter, you need to re-encode the stream. Just get rid of the -c:v copy argument or replace copy with video codec of your choice (e.g. h264).
